# Default username/password for Rstudio-server on GCP

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am using a **e2-standard-2** instance having Ubuntu 18.04 on Google Cloud Platform.
I have successfully installed Rstudio-server inside it. But I am not able to authorize myself as it is asking for username/password. Even I used the default username of my VM instance as username and instance id as password but no luck.

Please help !!!

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: How have you configured rstudio server? Which image (assuming docker/container) are you using? I think this is more appropriate for superuser.com, as it appears to be *not* programming but more computer/system administration.

Comment: Some other links (all included in the first link provided by @PorkChop: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/221303588-What-is-my-username-on-my-RStudio-Server- and https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200717203-RStudio-Server-Log-in-and-User-Authentication-Problems, both indicate that PAM is used ... so if you don't have a good idea of what PAM is and what it means on GCP, then now you know some "next questions". (Also on superuser, my guess.)

Answer (score 2):

RStudio server will use the same usernames and passwords as user accounts in your linux server it is installed on, except for privileged users.

What it means is that if you have root permissions, you won't be able to login using your linux credentials.

What you need to do instead is to create a new user on your linux server:

`useradd rstudio`

`passwd rstudio`

After that you can use rstudio/yournewpassword to login